# How to put a cite command next to a theorem with square brackets and no parentheses?

Tags: citing, cite-package, newtheorem

In my bachelor thesis, I use a theorem from another author. I have to cite him. When I use

```
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\begin{proposition}\textup{\cite[Proposition 4.7]{LPW}}
```

I get

[image]

This is not exactly what I want. As you can see, there is a point behind "Proposition 4.8". I want that point to be behind the last bracket, so that get

[image]

I hope I clarified my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note the additional braces: `\begin{proposition}[{\cite[Proposition 4.7]{LPW}}]`

Comment: But this gives me ([ *quote* ]). Can I eliminate the round brackets?

Comment: In your first picture there are parentheses (round brackets). Maybe you want `\begin{proposition}[Proposition 4.7 in \cite{LPW}]`. Or, if you prefer, `\begin{proposition}\textup{\cite[Proposition 4.7]{LPW}}`

Comment: Thank you egreg! Your last suggestion is almost perfect. Is it possible to put the point behind the quote? 
Right now I have Proposition 4.8. [Lev09, Proposition 4.7]
Can I get Proposition 4.8 [Lev09, Proposition 4.7]. ?

Comment: That requires much more work. Please, edit the question to show *exactly* what you need. Then we can reopen it, if in the meantime it gets closed.

Comment: egreg, I edited my question. I hope, it's clear now. Please reopen it. Thank you.

Comment: i extended the title to be more specific, to show that this is not the same as the suggested "duplicate".